# Send csv table with python without attachment

Tags: python, csv, sendmail

I am trying to send a csv table with python, but it isn't working. I don't need attachment, i want only the tabla (dataes) from this csv.

Here my code:

```
me = 'mail1'
    password = 'password'
    server = 'smtp.gmail.com:587'
    you = 'mail2'
    text = """
    Hello, Friend.

    Here is your data:

    {table}

    Regards,

    Me"""

    html = """
    <html><body><p>Hello, Friend.</p>
        <p>Here is your data:</p>
    {table}
        <p>Regards,</p>
    <p>Me</p>
    </body></html>
    """

    with open('test.csv') as input_file:
            content=input_file.read().decode("UTF-8")
            reader = csv.reader(content)
        data = list(reader)

    text = text.format(table=tabulate(data, headers="firstrow", tablefmt="grid"))
    html = html.format(table=tabulate(data, headers="firstrow", tablefmt="html"))

    message = MIMEMultipart(
        "alternative", None, [MIMEText(text), MIMEText(html,'html')])

    message['Subject'] = "Your data"
    message['From'] = me
    message['To'] = you
    server = smtplib.SMTP(server)
    server.ehlo()
    server.starttls()
    server.login(me, password)
    server.sendmail(me, you, message.as_string())
    server.quit()
```

What am I wrong? I am using Python 2.7

Edit:

```
Error: "'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 0: 
     ordinal not in range(128) first failed due to some error "
```

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: @Mr.D: [Edit] your Question and show the **Full Traceback**.

Comment: I get only this one :)

Comment: @Mr.D: *"I get only this one"* Your `with open..` looks faulty. Remove the line `content=input_file...` and change to `... csv.reader(input_file)`

Comment: I get the same error message with this too. There is someting character issu, because in this csv there are á,é,ű,ó,etc characters

Comment: 'encoding' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Comment: @Mr.D: On 2.7 you need `import codecs; codecs.open('test.csv', encoding="utf-8")`

Comment: it isn't working:            with codecs.open('test.csv', encoding="utf-8"):
    # with open('test.csv') as input_file:
            reader = csv.reader(input_file)
            data = list(reader)